# How to sort list of objects within renerItem of flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting, react-native-flatlist

Hello I want to sort an object within `renderItem` of `FlatList`.I'm getting array of objects as server response.I want to do sorting within these objects.I've a list of cars with their price. If the user click on sort button of car with lowest price first.I want to show the cars with lowest price first in the list.The structure of `item` within `renderItem` is as follows.

[image]

The expanded structure of single `item` is as follows.I want to sort the object by its `priceTotal`.

[image]

Following is my code which I've done so far.Please help to find a solution.

**sample code**

```
 renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
          <CarReservationDetailComponent
            carName={item.make}
            carType={item.carType}
            carPrice1={item.priceTotal}
            mileage
            mileageText={item.autonomy + 'km. restantes'}
            imageUri={item.picture}
          />
        )
      }
    .....
    <FlatList
                  data={this.props.value.value}
                  renderItem={this.renderItems}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
```

Comment: you can pass a  callback function from the parent component and onlclick of sort button the parent component shuold sort the items list.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you.Could you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  sortItemByKey = key => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const clonedItems = items.map(item => ({ ...item }));
    clonedItems.sort(compare);
    this.setState({ items: clonedItems });

    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.State;
    return (
      <View>
        <ChildComponent value={{ value: items }} sortByKey={this.sortItemByKey} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  // you should bind this method to onclick of sort button
  onClick = () => {
    this.props.sortByKey('priceTotal');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.value.value}
        renderItem={this.renderItems}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So how do display the sorted list within `renderItem`?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean within `sortItemByKey ` method we will get the sorted result So within the renderItem of `FlatList` the sorted result will be within `item` right?

Comment: yes, when we sort the items. The sorted list will passed as a props to child component and renderItem method will get the item in the sorted order.